# Perforce stream copy wants to delete files

Tags: perforce, perforce-stream

I just finished merging down some changes from a parent stream into a child stream. Somehow the merge missed a bunch of new files in the parent that needed to be created in the child stream (and I didn't notice). So now the files exist in the parent but not in the child.

Now that I'm copying back up into the parent, it wants to delete all those missing files. I can't re-merge from parent to child because perforce says there are no outstanding changes to merge. How can I fix this?

#### Update

Here are the settings for force integration in p4v:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like when you did the merge, you opted to "ignore" (aka "accept yours" or "accept target" depending which UI you're using) the new files.  This is essentially the same as if you ignore a changed a file during a merge; the child will retain the original (unmodified) version of the file, and when you copy back to the parent, the child's version will overwrite the parent's version, eliminating the changes that you ignored.

If the ignore was a mistake, you can use `p4 integrate -f` to force another merge/resolve.  Alternatively, if you already know that you just want the child to have an exact copy of what's in the parent (i.e. you aren't trying to merge individual changes), you can use `p4 copy -F` to copy in the "wrong" direction (from parent to child) so that the child will get the same version of the file that the parent currently has.

Comment: Great, thank you for the advice. I don't really use the command line so I'm trying to figure it out inside p4v. If I right click on the child stream and select `Merge/Integrate to 'my-child-stream'` I see the merge dialog. From there I can click on `Set Defaults...` at the bottom. Then I get another dialog and under `Behavior -> Integrate flags` there is a checkbox that says `Force integration on all revisions, disregarding integration history (-f)`. Should I check that box and retry? See my post for pics.

Comment: FYI, I went ahead and tried to set the `-f` flag I mentioned above in pv4 but perforce is still telling me there is nothing to merge down. Maybe that's the wrong setting?

Comment: I recommend shooting Perforce tech support an email.  Maybe there's something unusual in the stream definition -- normally I'd debug that by running `p4 client -o` and `p4 branch -o -S <stream>`, but I'm not sure how you'd go about figuring it out in P4V.